# How to define a class in which certain edges are obligatory for all assigned records in OrientDB?

Tags: class, orientdb, graph-databases

I want to create a class, so that every record added has the obligation to have prior defined edges.

As an example I have a class called "hip prosthesis", where various hip prosthesis shall be recorded.

A hip prosthesis has a uniform basic design (shaft, head), but the prosthesis differ in the characteristics of these parts (dimension, material, etc.) and the deployment method (cemented or cementless) used.

The easiest way might be to have the characteristics as properties (e.g. “shaft dimension”, “head material”, “deployment method”) of the class and make them mandatory.

Nevertheless for further use I rather want to have a node for each of these properties (e.g. “cemented”) and make the edges (e.g. “HasDeploymentMethod”) an obligation for each of the records depending on the assigned class.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined your main class?

Acoording with the [documentation](https://orientdb.com/docs/2.2.x/SQL-Create-Property.html), you can create your main class and in every property that you want to be obligatory, set the field (that you want to related in the respective edge) as a mandatory field, e.g:

```
CREATE PROPERTY User.name STRING (MANDATORY TRUE, MIN 5, MAX 25)
```

Comment: To my understandung your answer describes the "easiest way", I already excluded in my question. Or ist there a way to automatically extend the properties to edges?